# A word for 'treated-out' or 'therapied-out' - all medical treatment exhausted without effect

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the following:

A patient who has received all possible medical treatment but all of them have failed to initiate a cure or remission. The patient cannot be (meaningfully) helped according to conventional medicine. The patient's illness does not necessarily have to be a terminal disease.

Hence: **The patient is 'treated-out' or 'therapied-out'.**

I'm aware that 'treated-out' and 'therapied-out' do not exist as such, and currently I don't intend to use them.

The word or two-worded term I'm looking for could be the counterpart to the German word 'austherapiert'.

**NOTE:** I'm NOT looking for untreatable patient, terminal-stage patient, palliative care, palliative treatment, or palliative care patient

I am looking for a word or two-worded term that relates to the patient and implies that essentially all conceivable treatment has been tried and applied, unsuccessfully.

---

(UPDATE)

### THE MOST APPROPRIATE TERMS FOUND

The following expressions seem to match best for non-terminal diseases:

- all treatment options exhausted
- a treatment-exhausted patient
- 'therapied out' - seems to be an uncommon but more and more frequently used term, according to the search results on Google Books but much less in scientific literature; bear in mind Google's Ngram Viewer has no entries for 'therapied out' (Ngram Viewer version 2012/2013, as available on 22 Nov 2018)

For terminal diseases, these were found (not mentioned above):

- an end-stage patient
- infaust-prognosis patient

Comment: how about ***untreatable***

Comment: I don't know of anybody who would use a single word. Of if there even is one that means *a patient for whom all known treatments have been exhausted*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Even if it is two words, eventually hyphened, that's fine.

Comment: @Jim - Yes, treatment options are exhausted.

Comment: The problem with out-treated, is that it will be perceived in the same manner as out-paced, out-matched, out-gunned etc.

Comment: To clarify, is this somebody who has *actually* had many possible treatments attempted? Or is that incidental to the *diagnosis* that there is no treatment going forward? Did you rule out *untreatable* because they *were* treated, simply ineffectively?

Comment: @JasonBassford - Yes, the patient has received treatment but treatment has not lead to any positive sign and the patient continues in their debilitating state. 'Untreatable' implies that nothing can be done anyway (a kind of). I look for a term that implies that everything possible has been done but without success.

Comment: @Jim - I totally agree, out-treated etc. does not sound good. I'm not intending to use it. ..Even if 'out' is put at the end, it still sounds extremely awkward and highly unnatural.

Comment: Don't you think that's backwards?

What, exactly, according to at least three or four and preferably five or six medical dictionaries does "'austherapiert'' leave unclear?

At the most basic level, consider please https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/austherapiert.html

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin - I don't think it's backwards at all. The translations on linguee seem to be facing the same problem, which is using/finding an expression that goes together with the word patient but also refers to the treatment and that it is exhausted. I personally find the translation examples on linguee long-winded to convey the meaning. Maybe 'treatment-exhausted patient' is the most appropriate formulation, because this is what 'austherapiert' actually means.

Comment: I believe one sees: all treatment options have been exhausted. that therapy out is really bad, so treat out. https://www.google.com/search?ei=WBDzW4LWJajl_Qbu8aOACA&q=%22all++treatment+options+have+been+exhausted%22+-cancer&oq=%22all++treatment+options+have+been+exhausted%22+-cancer&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4327.7116..7391...3.0..0.150.808.9j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i299j33i22i29i30.BE8zBUYnSlA

Comment: Jolly good, johann_ka. Why does that mean linguee or any other translation service is wrong?

"Therapied out" will always be understood by any half-way educated speaker of English but that doesn't make it anything like an acceptable technical term.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - I totally agree with you, this is why, in my initial post, I have noted that I'm aware that it is not 'official terminology' and that I'm not intending to use 'therapied out'. ..However, using it might make it popular in times of Google and the internet. ;-)

Comment: Yes,  johann_ka; it is generally and should technically be recognised…

By the way, when you posted "in times of " did that mean "in terms of " or what?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - I meant 'in times of' ... not the best adaptation of 'in times of trouble'. What I meant to say was that nowadays, English grammar is being 'abused' all over the internet to an unprecedented extent. One 'simply' reuses a wrong expression over and over and sooner or later it will be picked up and find its way into the general, accepted vocabulary.

Comment: @johann_ka How was my answer not the accepted one? I suggest “refractory” 1.5 days before the answer you accepted, and offered an anecdote to demonstrate that it’s commonly used. Did you need me to copy the entry from a dictionary or something?

Comment: @mRotten - The bounty was automatically assigned by the system because it had the most upvotes. Please keep in mind, that I personally did and do not hold the opinion that the answer provided by you ("refractory") was what I was looking for. The reason is that I was looking for an expression that directly refers to the patient (and indirectly to the disease) for combinations such as 'NEEDED-WORD patient'. Though, I honestly appreciate your input and please keep posting answers in this forum.

Comment: So the accepted answer wasn’t what you were looking for? Wow, what a brilliant system - you ask for a word, and everyone else decides which answer best fits your needs.

Comment: @mRotten - I agree with you that the automatic assignment of bounty by the system is suboptimal. Just for the records, I find the bester indicating answer was provided by the use 'Airport Chariot Car and Limo' but he did not explain anything apart from copying a link. Hence, I decided to not give the bounty to him.

Answer (score 4):

From Webster's New World Medical Dictionary, 3rd ed:

> **refractory** Not yielding, or not yielding readily, to treatment.

*As the patient had refractory hemispheric epilepsy, a commissurotomy was performed.*

Comment: Thank you for your input. Do you think this would imply 'treatment options are exhausted' ?

Comment: It means that they've not been getting better from  treatment, with the implicit assumption being that if one treatment failed you'd try another.

Comment: +1. An online source would have been ideal, but citing Webster's NWMD is certainly sufficient, and your edit now makes this a valid answer, although tying it in to the OP's request for description of the *patient* would be a further improvement. Just one minor point: is the example sentence your own, or given in Webster's? If the latter, it should be included within the blockquote formatting to make this clear.

Comment: @faustus - I see. It is a good word but I'm looking for something that precedes the word 'patient', so that the layperson 'a kind of understands' what is being spoken about.

Comment: @johann_ka then i think treatment resistant is your best bet.

Comment: @faustus - hmm, since the start of this beneficial conversation here I have mulled over this a lot and I start to think of 'treatment-exhausted patient'.

Answer (score 3):

### [treatment resistant](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11480879)

> ...are treatment resistant in the sense that the majority do not
> achieve full remission with the first somatic or psychosocial
> treatment they receive.

There is however, no stable definition of [treatment resistant](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10372602):

> The definition of treatment resistance remains controversial in spite
> of its importance. This review discusses the importance of treatment
> resistance and the factors affecting its definition in the light of
> recent advances in knowledge and treatment.

And [again](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11480879):

> Little attention has been given to formalizing criteria for evaluating
> the nature and extent of treatment resistance, even though determining
> the adequacy and outcome of prior treatment trials is key in clinical
> decision making about subsequent treatment.

Comment: Thanks for your post, Duck...  Not sure if the paper mentioned by you was written by a native speaker. To me, treatment resistance implies that the patient is resistant whereas 'treatment response' would relate to the illness and its treatment, and the treatment's effect.

Comment: @johann_ka The first and third references are from a North American born psychologist, Harold A. Sackeim's paper. The second reference, is as you may observe from Jozef Peuskens' paper, who is a native of  Belgium...

Comment: ... @johann_ka in western medicine, it is the paradigm to diagnose and describe conditions, not to characterise patients independant of such criteria, ie. the condition is treatment-resistant not the patient.

Comment: I don't contradict this, but I would like to find a word that relates to the patient. In other languages, there are words for this. E.g. 'austherapiert' in German.

Comment: @johann_ka Understood, I'll make a second answer.

Answer (score 3):

There was a discussion about this in 2005 on proz.com
The two most popular translations of austherapiert were:

1. (have/has) exhausted all therapeutical options
2. therapied out

However, the proz.com OP chose "all treatment options exhausted" as her preferred answer. You can view the discussion thread on the link below.

https://www.proz.com/kudoz/german-to-english/medical-general/1181660-austherapiert.html

Comment: Your answer needs to contain an actual answer, not just a link to one. Please edit your answer to include what's relevant so it isn't deleted. See [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/323179) for more information.

Comment: @Airport ... - Thank you for replying. One would say 'treatment-exhausted patient' or 'all-treatment-exhausted patient'? 'Exhausted' is already in the title of the post, but still valuable input from you. Thank you!

Comment: therapied out is a monstrosity. Typical crap one sees on proz. However, exhausting treatment options is kosher, for sure. I'm only upvoting the exhaustion/exhaust one.

Comment: therapeutical is a mistake on Proz. exhausted all "treatment options"

Answer (score 2):

I’ve worked with infectious disease docs who treat HIV+ patients and say that a patient “failed” a treatment (e.g. “failed Atripla”), as if the patient gave the drug an ‘F’ for the semester or something. It seems odd to say because it likely wasn’t the patient’s fault, so while I might not agree with this phrasing, the phrasing is nonetheless used to indicate that the drug is no longer effective. Another problem is that I've only heard "failed” to refer to the most recent Tx option, and HIV+ patients rarely run out of options, so I can only assume that a doc would say that a patient “failed ARV treatment” if no other options were left.

In referring to aggressive tumors, oncologists I’ve worked with use “recalcitrant” or “refractory” (e.g. “a treatment-refractory tumor”, or "...tumor is recalcitrant to treatment") to indicate the tumor won’t respond or will no longer respond to drug treatment. I think that might be what you’re looking for.

Comment: Upvoted as I consider your input valuable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your desire for a term that “relates to the patient” (and not to the condition) makes this question difficult, for as pointed out by @Duckisaduckisaduck in [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/472637/a-word-for-treated-out-or-therapied-out-all-medical-treatment-exhausted-wi/472650#comment1141306_472650),

> in western medicine, it is the paradigm to diagnose and describe
>   conditions, not to characterise patients independant of such criteria,
>   ie. the condition is treatment-resistant not the patient.

Personally, I like “Duck’s” answer of “treatment-resistant” (+1) and with the context/particular condition well established, perhaps that answer could apply/transfer to the patient, i.e.,

> With regard to his/her [heart/skin/mental/etc] condition, the patient
>   is treatment/therapy-resistant.

Regardless, even if there is a perfect English term relating **solely** to the patient (as “austherapiert” seems to do in German), I think it would still be necessary to preface its use with a mention of the particular condition at issue.  Without such a context-setting reference, it might sound as if the patient is “[all] treated-out” for any and all conditions that s/he might have now or in the future.

With this need (as I see it) to include/restate (even to the point of redundancy) the particular condition at issue in mind (along with my [probably incorrect] assumption that you are not necessarily limiting your search to formal medical/clinical terms), maybe you could consider something like:

> With regard to his/her [heart/skin/mental/etc] condition, the patient
>   is **[therapeutically] out-of-options.**

(cf: [this (albeit sans hyphens and the veterinarian’s, not the patient’s) use](https://www.petmd.com/blogs/thedailyvet/aobrien/2013/nov/alternative-holistic-medicine-for-horses-large-animals-31082) of the above suggestion  in the last paragraph  of Dr. O’Brien’s entry from *petmd.com*)

Answer (score 1):

How about

> The patient is **incurable**.

Although most often applied to ailments, it can also be applied to people.  See for example [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incurable):

> 1 (of a sick person or a disease) not able to be cured.

Answer (score 1):

Expleitively attenuated

Inconsequentially attritioned

Entropic results

Modalities exasperated

Therapy Tanking

Evaporative resolve

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[intractable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intractable) 1

[intractable](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/intractable#intractable__1) 2

intractable: adjective

1

> formal: very difficult or impossible to deal with

2

> Stubborn; obstinate (of a person)

Comment: I have voted your two answers up. You seem very committed and although the quest hasn't been cracked yet, your post is very valuable input.

Comment: @johann_ka Thanks, I'm curious to know how this goes too, though I'm bowing out for now. I'll brew popcorn and watch.

Answer (score 0):

You could say the disease is *recalcitrant* to treatment.

[**recalcitrant**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/recalcitrant) - (adj.)

1. Marked by a stubborn unwillingness to obey authority.
2. Unwilling to cooperate socially.
3. Difficult to deal with or to operate.

This word is used to describe hard-to-treat [cancers](https://cancerdiscovery.aacrjournals.org/content/2/11/965.2) and antibiotic-resistant [infections](http://criticalcare.imedpub.com/a-case-series-of-emergency-investigational-new-drug-applications-for-bacteriophages-treating-recalcitrant-multidrug-resistant-bact.php?aid=24591).

Comment: The OP is insistent on wanting a word to describe the *patient*; it would be very inappropriate to describe the patient in this situation as recalcitrant.

Comment: @BryanKrause I understand that the OP asked for a word describing the patient, though the current top answer - *refractory*, meaning stubborn or unmanageable - also describes the ineffectiveness of treatment relative to the disease.  Obviously, it would be inappropriate to describe the patient as *refractory* or *recalcitrant*, which is why I explicitly state "You could say the **disease** is recalcitrant to treatment."

Comment: @Dirigible - The accepted answer was assigned automatically by the system as there was a bounty on this question. I would not have picked that answer. Thanks for your suggestion!